# HTML table cells aren't uniform width in Firefox, fine in Chrome and IE8

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, html-table

I'm working on an app in ASP.NET MVC 2, and the output of the table looks the way I'd expect in Chrome and IE8:

[image]

but this is how it looks in FF 3.6.8 it looks like this:

[image]

I'm using Javascript/jQuery to add rows, this is the code:

```
        function onAddItem() {
        itemCount = itemCount + 1;
        var rowString = "<tr id=" + itemCount + ">";
        rowString = rowString + "<td>" + document.getElementById("Order_productcode").value + "</td>";
        rowString = rowString + "<td>" + document.getElementById("Order_productsku").value + "</td>";
        rowString = rowString + "<td>" + document.getElementById("Order_productdesc").value + "</td>";
        rowString = rowString + "<td align=\"right\">" + document.getElementById("ItemQuantity").value + "</td>";
        rowString = rowString + "<td>" + document.getElementById("Order_productweight").value + "</td>";
        rowString = rowString + "<td>" + document.getElementById("Order_productcost").value + "</td>";
        rowString = rowString + "</tr>";
        $row = $(rowString);
        $row.hide().fadeIn("slow").appendTo("#orderedItems table tbody");
    }
```

Looking in Firebug, I found the row that gets created looks like this:

```
 <tr style="display: block;" id="1"><td>EC5931A-Tote</td><td>100002</td><td></td><td align="right"></td><td>0</td><td>33250.00</td></tr></tbody>
```

that is, it adds `style="display: block;"`, which seems to be the problem (when I edited it out in Firebug, it looked correct, i.e., like in IE and Chrome).   Why is Firefox doing that, and how can I make it stop?

EDIT: I removed the `.hide().fadeIn("slow")` and now it's working correctly in Firefox.  Seems to be a bug in jQuery with Firefox, although I didn't see it on the jQuery site.

Comment: FYI, tried this on jquery 1.4.1 and 1.4.2, buggy in both.

Comment: You should have tagged this jquery. That's probably where you want to look first.

Comment: There's also an invalid id, an id has to start with a letter or underscore, from memory. I'm sure that ids *starting* with numbers are invalid. Oh, and in this kind of question you're probably best off posting the generated mark-up (that the browser sees, with the 'view source' option), rather than the server-side code that generates it.

Comment: @David Thomas: you had originally put your comments in as an answer, and I responded to them -- by changing my code to start with a string, both  "row-" and "row", which did not help.  Then your answers were deleted, presumably by you, which took my comments with them.  Now you post the same thing, so I'll say again, that didn't make a difference.  Also, the second code block above in my post shows the generated mark-up; this was in the original post, so that was covered from the get go.

Comment: No, I didn't. I haven't answered the question because when I first saw the question you'd already added your edit that it was working correctly. O.o

Comment: My mistake; someone else had posted the same thing, to which I responded that I'd tried the changes and they didn't make a difference, but that person has since deleted his answer and my response with it. Thought it was you.